# SQL Top 5 and the rest as others

Tags: oracle

I want to select the top 5 rows and additional a 6th row named Others with rest aggregated.

with
Anzahl as
(SELECT
NVL (parse_listener_log_line (connect_string, 'HOST'), 'n/a') host, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM listener_log
       WHERE ID_MANDANT = :P100_MANDANT
       AND    ID_SERVER = :P100_SERVER
    GROUP BY parse_listener_log_line (connect_string, 'HOST')
    ORDER BY cnt DESC),
client as
(select
    case
        when rownum > 4 then 'Others'
    else host
end as client, cnt
FROM Anzahl)
SELECT client, cnt
FROM client;

CLIENT          CNT
**jdbc**    118553
server2     106170
server1     101710
server4      13370
Others        8734 
Others        1760
Others        1365
Others        1058

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of analytic functions (`row_number`) along with set operations (`union`) might do what you're looking for.

Scott's EMP table contains these data:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000
FORD             3000
SCOTT            3000
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
ALLEN            1600
TURNER           1500
MILLER           1300
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
ADAMS            1100
JAMES             950
SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

Now: find each row's ordinal number (using `row_number`) and union the first 5 rows (take each of them *as is*) with the sixth one that contains aggregated salaries:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select ename,
  3            sal,
  4            row_number() over (order by sal desc) rn
  5     from emp
  6    )
  7  select rn,
  8         ename,
  9         sal
 10  from temp
 11  where rn <= 5
 12  union all
 13  select 6,
 14         'Other',
 15         sum(sal)
 16  from temp
 17  where rn > 5
 18  order by rn;

        RN ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 KING             5000
         2 SCOTT            3000
         3 FORD             3000
         4 JONES            2975
         5 BLAKE            2850
         6 Other           12200

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```